# How to mock a class that is created in a function (new operator)?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I am trying to mock a class that is created in function.

```
function pon_validate_device(DB $db, Logger $logger, $request, $mode = 'add') {
    ...

    $testConnection = new Telnet(...);

    $testConnection->login();

    return true;
}
```

Is there any way to mock the telnet class and control the response of the login function?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to mock the telnet class and control the response of the login function?

Not easily. Creating a mock of the telnet class *is* easy, but as the `pon_validate_device()` function creates the concrete **Telent** object (**`new`**`Telnet()`), there is no easy way to inject the mock to be in use at the place where its login method is called:

```php
    $testConnection = new Telnet(...);

    $testConnection->login();
```

So you should consider it impossible unless function `pon_validate_device()` allows the injection, for example with an (additional) function parameter:

```php
function pon_validate_device(
    DB $db,
    Logger $logger,
    $request, $mode = 'add',
    Telnet $testConnection = null,  #  new parameter
) {
    ...

    $testConnection ?= new Telnet(...);

    $testConnection->login();

    return true;
}
```

You can then inject (in your test) the mock.

It is possible to make such a dependency even more obvious by making it a *non-optional* parameter.

---

As the function already has four (three plus one optional) parameters, it seems it is getting a bit crowded already.

An alternative to the parameter injection is constructor injection. This may require you to turn the function into an object and instantiate it:

```php
class PonDevice {
    public function __construct(
        private DB $db, 
        private Logger $logger, 
        private Telnet $telnet,
    ) {}
    
    ...

    public function validate($request, $mode = 'add') {

        ...

        $this->telnet->login(???);

        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can already see in this quick example, it might bubble up initialization requirements, e.g. what was parameterized in

```php
$testConnection = new Telnet(...);
```

has now already been injected, so the Telnet class may need additional changes (which could be good in case the Telnet constructor did real work which normally is frowned upon as it make such classes hard to use in tests - extract the configuration from constructor injection into a method with parameters, quickly sketched with the question marks:

```php
        $this->telnet->login(???);
```

Much words already, the main takeaway should be that if a test shows that some code is hard to test, it perhaps revealed previously more hidden dependencies. Consider for a moment what is going on and consider if the code could benefit from a change of the design (there is only benefit if it makes the system under test easier to use/develop for you, e.g. testing works like a breeze and you can then much quicker and safer change even more code).

---

And now for the dirty parts (this is a slippery when wet and its always wet situation):

Given the code under test hast not yet been executed and more importantly there never has been the **Telnet** class instantiated *and* autoloading is in use, you can "mock" the Telnet class definition by replacing it with your own one (with the same class-name).

When the code then is executed, it will instantiate the Telnet object based on that class definition as there would be nothing to auto-load any longer.

However this requires you to fully duplicate the Telnet class and then add for that test double'd class specific test-points to inject the test-only behaviour and properties.

As you can imagine this is cumbersome, unstable, a mess to maintain and to no extend improving the code under test.

However I thought as you asked for it, it should be at least mentioned in the answer.